# package ‘twitterR’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)

Tags: r

I'm beginner for R. when i download twitterR package 
I got a error message like

> Installing package into ‘/home/xxx/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘twitterR’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps it is because you have spelled the name wrong?

```
install.packages("twitteR") # not twitterR
```